# How to use new Rupee Symbol of India in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

How can i use `Rupee` Symbol in `Silverlight` can any one tell how to implement this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the unicode representation and that is `20B9` if I am not wrong.

You could have a look at

```
http://techpp.com/2010/10/12/indian-rupee-symbol-unicode-standard/
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you googled that?
I did a search on "rupee symbol silverlight" and the first two results are very relevant

1. [How to use Rupee symbol of Indiaa in Silverlight?](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article954-how-to-use-new-rupee-symbol-of-india-in-silverlight-.aspx)
2. [How to Use New Rupee Symbol of India in Silverlight?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/NewIndianRupeeSymbolDemo.aspx)